# Git: any downside to changing email mid project

Tags: git, github

What happens when you change your git email (`git config --local name.email "me@example.com"`) mid-project? Would I then appear as a different collaborator?

What about with GitHub? Is it important to keep your submitter email in sync with your GitHub email address?

Just trying to get my personal email out of the repo (at least for future commits) and trying to do it the right way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "collaborator" in Git. All that would happen is that your new commits would have a different email associated with them.

In Github, your commits would be attributed to an unknown account, unless you associate that email with your Github account. You can have as many emails attached to your Github account as you want, and any commits using those emails will be attributed to you.